# Fill a column with the current date when user add or change other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to find a way to fill a column (let's say A) with the current date, or TODAY() function, when a user adds or changes the same row.

For instance, A1 will get filled with 2/7/11 if I add something to B1 or edit C1. Notice that they are all on the same row.

Is this possible in excel? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you're looking for: (right-click the tab / View Code).

The code puts the now() value in cell Rxxx

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim Lijn
   Dim Cel

   Lijn = Target.Row
   Cel = "R" & Trim(Str(Lijn))
   Range(Cel).Value = Now()

End Sub
```